# Set based solution to update nulls to Last Known Value in ordered table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To maintain my purity and honor as a database dork, I wish to update a set of datetimes and floats that has some nulls in the float column such that each null value will be replaced by the previous (by datetime) non-null value.

My environment is mssql 2k8R2.

I hope the following snippet explains my victory conditions sufficiently.

Cheers and Thanks.

```
create table #datesAndValues(
    [Date] datetime,
    Val float);
create table #resultsShouldLookLikeThis(
    [Date] datetime,
    Val float);

insert into #datesAndValues 
values  
    ('1/8/11',1.1),
    ('1/7/11',null),
    ('1/6/11',1.2),
    ('1/5/11',null),
    ('1/4/11',null),
    ('1/3/11',1.3),
    ('1/2/11',null),
    ('1/1/11',null);

/*  
    set based code (no loops!!!) goes here to set nulls
    in the above table to the last known good (not null) value,
    thereby making it look like the following table.
*/

insert into #resultsShouldLookLikeThis
values  
    ('1/8/11',1.1),
    ('1/7/11',1.2),
    ('1/6/11',1.2),
    ('1/5/11',1.3),
    ('1/4/11',1.3),
    ('1/3/11',1.3),
    ('1/2/11',null),
    ('1/1/11',null);

--this will tell us if it worked
select 'In old but not new' as [WhichTable], o.*
from    (select * from #datesAndValues
        except select * from #resultsShouldLookLikeThis) o
union all
select 'In new but not old' as [WhichTable], n.*
from    (select * from #resultsShouldLookLikeThis
        except select * from #datesAndValues) n;

drop table #datesAndValues;
drop table #resultsShouldLookLikeThis;
```

Comment: as a database dork you should also acknowledge when cursors are the best tool for the job! It would be possible to do this without cursors but you would be replacing a single scan through the data with potentially quite a heavy weight query. You might want to vote for some of Itzik's suggested `OVER` clause enhancements here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254388/over-clause-enhancement-request-lag-and-lead-functions

Comment: Indeed, Martin, the Engineer in me always seeks the pragmatic, but since I was stuck for a set based solution, I had no ability to measure the two approaches. Now, thanks to be to Conrad, I do. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update #datesAndValues set
  Val = (select top 1 Val
         from #datesAndValues as T2
         where
          T2.[Date] < T.[Date] and
          T2.Val is not null
         order by [Date] desc)
from #datesAndValues as T         
where T.Val is null
```

Comment: That is the sort of clarity I was seeking, Mikael. It is beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to note here.

The second level of Inline SQL is required otherwise you get an ambiguous `#datesAndValues` on the update. (maybe there's a better way to solve that)

The second thing to note is that two of the values will still be null since there is no previous value for `1/1/11` and `1/2/11`

Finally as Martin notes. A cursor solution is probably better anyway

```
UPDATE
    #datesAndValues 
SET 
   Val = newVal.val
FROM
    #datesAndValues d1
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
       maxVal.OldDate,
       newValue.Val 
     FROM 
       #datesAndValues newValue
        INNER JOIN 
        (
                SELECT
                  t.[Date] oldDate, max(t2.[Date]) NewDate
                 FROM 
                   #datesAndValues   t
                   INNER JOIN #datesAndValues  t2
                   ON t.[Date] > t2.Date
                      and t2.Val is not null
                 WHERE
                   t.Val is null

                 GROUP BY
                   t.[Date]
        )  maxVal
        on NewValue.[Date] = maxVal.NewDate)  newVal
        ON d1.Date= newVal.oldDate
```

Here's an alternative using DENSE_RANK

```
WITH Cte as 
(Select 
   dv.Date ,
   dv2.val newval,
    DENSE_RANK () OVER (partition by dv.Date order by dv2.Val) RANK
From 
    #datesAndValues dv
    INNER JOIN #datesAndValues dv2
    ON dv.[date] > dv2.[date]
        AND dv.val is null
       and dv2.val is not null
)
UPDATE 
    #datesAndValues
SET 
    val = Cte.newval
FROM 
    #datesAndValues dv
    INNER JOIN Cte 
    ON dv.Date = cte.Date
WHERE
    Cte.RANK = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Conrad. Yes, when there is no previous known good value in the data set, I expected nulls (hence the nulls in the #resultsShouldLookLikeThis table). I'll endeavor to set up a bit of a test case at lunch, now that I can. Happy Monday to you.